# PowerPoint VBA - SlideRange position on a screen

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I am creating a PPT Add-In and I am struggling to find the answer whether it is possible to determine the SlideRange position on a screen.

I would like to have a userform to be opened in a particular position (for example left = 10, top = 10 starting from left-top corner of the SlideRange). Unfortunatelly its position is based on a screen resolution. As the resolution can be changed and the PPT view type may be modified I am unable to establish the accurate position of SlideRange.

Is it possible to do with VBA?

Thanks in advance!
MJ

Answer (score 1):

SlideRange has no particular position ... it's a collection of slides, and it's unclear what units you're using when you want to position the form at 10,10.  But in normal full screen view, you can get the slide show window coordinates in points like so:

With SlideShowWindows(1)
    Debug.Print .Left
    Debug.Print .Top
    Debug.Print .Height
    Debug.Print .Width
End With

To get the results in screen pixels you have to use a Win API call to get the screen DPI (dots per inch).

Inches = Points / 72 
Pixels = Inches * DPI

Comment: Hi Steve,
Thank you for your answer. Good to know that there is no way to find a slide position.
I am trying to create a floating ruler (userform) that shows its current posiotion which will help me to align objects.
I realised that it can be replaced by a picture and a separate userform will show current picture position.
I faced another obstacle which is a lack of MouseUp/Down event in PPT.
WindowSelectionChange does not solve the problem... Do you know if it is possible to catch mouse events in PPT?
Thanks
MJ

Answer (score 1):

<< Do you know if it is possible to catch mouse events in PPT?

Only if the mouseclick changes the selection, and as you know, that's NOT all the time.

There's probably some way of doing it via the Win API but nothing like this is built into PPT itself.